# Trying to put an XML sitemap into AWS S3 bucket via NodeJS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have configured an AWS S3 bucket in order to store sitemap XML files. These will be periodically updated by some functions residing in AWS lambdas. I have a lambda sending a sitemap.xml object (this is not an actual file, it is a sitemap that is built after a site crawl, and then formatted as XML on the fly) to my S3 bucket, however nothing happens. I get no errors in the lambda logs, nor the S3 logs. My lambda that is trying to make a request to S3 has `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy attached.

I can see in the S3 logs that it gets triggered, and the logs show all 200s, but I do not see my data in the S3 bucket. In order to troubleshoot, I even loosened up the S3 Bucket Policy to accept all requests. Still no luck.

One oddity is that my S3 bucket continues to generate logs endlessly once it has been triggered; long after my request has been closed. When I open the log files, some of them show a bunch of successful put requests, and others show 404s and all types of errors from requests that I'm not even making! For example, I tried to write to my S3 bucket last evening. This morning I had 300 logs files generated, but nothing in my S3 bucket. The log files had 200s, 400s, 404s, depending of the type of request (REST.GET.BUCKET, BATCH.DELETE.OBJECT, REST.GET.NOTIFICATION, REST.GET.WEBSITE, REST.PUT.BUCKETPOLICY, etc.) I'm only making a PUT request so I have no idea why the logs are showing all of those requests.

Here's my code:

`[bunch of imports and AWS config stuff]`

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {
  let urlArray;
  let metadataArray;
  let sitemapObject;
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);

  try {
    // separating two different arrays of objects from an outer array    
    metadataArray = parsedData[0];
    urlArray = parsedData[1];

    const newlyMergedArray = await mergeSpecificDataFromBothArrays(urlArr, vidArr);

    sitemapObject = await generateSitemap(newlyMergedArray);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }

    const dispatchToS3 = () => {

    const params = {
      Body: sitemapObject,
      Bucket: 'sitemap-service-s3',
      Key: 'my_website.com/sitemap.xml'
    };

    s3.putObject(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(this.httpResponse.body.toString());
        console.log(this.httpResponse.headers);
        console.log(error.stack);
        throw error;
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  };

try {
    await dispatchToS3();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

`sitemapObject` is an object that has been converted to XML right before I send it to S3. Can S3 accept XML? If so, should I apply `JSON.stringify` to it before `putObject` is executed? Although, I have tried sending sitemapObject as stringified and non-stringified data. The `putObject` does nothing in either case. Should I be sending this data as an actual JSON object instead of XML format?

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url>
<loc>https://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/video_url</loc>
<video:video>
<video:title>Video Title/video:title>
<video:description/>
<video:thumbnail_loc>http://mywebsite.com/path/to/thumbnail</video:thumbnail_loc>
<video:player_loc>https://third_party_video_hosting_site.com/path/to/player</video:player_loc>
<video:duration>2:06</video:duration>
</video:video>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/video_url</loc>
<video:video>
<video:title>Video Title/video:title>
<video:description/>
<video:thumbnail_loc>http://mywebsite.com/path/to/thumbnail</video:thumbnail_loc>
<video:player_loc>https://third_party_video_hosting_site.com/path/to/player</video:player_loc>
<video:duration>2:06</video:duration>
</video:video>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Here's my S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy12345678910",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt12345678910",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*" // this wildcard is for troubleshooting only. I would make this more specific/secure once I'm no longer troubleshooting.
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sitemap-service-s3/my_website.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you added S3 permissions to the Lambda function?

Comment: please, show your full code, who resolve dispatchToS3 ? Where does the sitemapObject variable come from?

Comment: @ene_salinas Thanks, I've added those details.

Comment: @Stephen my lambda has AmazonS3FullAccess policy attached.

Comment: Did you select a vpc for your lambda function?